# jQuery mouseout on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad, safari

I have a jQuery code which works perfect on desktop browsers;

```
$("span#checkbox_err").mouseout(function () {
                        $("span#checkbox_err").fadeOut("slow");
                    });
```

But the same does not trigger on the iPad (as a result the checkbox_err is displayed on screen, but never hides)

How do I trigger the mouseout event on the iPad ?

Also I'll want to avoid using any additional library just to fix this small issue..

**I HAVE A FOLLOW UP QUESTION**

I am testing a page on iPad and am facing some issues implementing an equivalent of mouseout behavior..

So the issue is very simple to understand; 1. On my page, there is a checkbox on click (or rather touch), I want to show an errorMsg 2. On click/touch on anything other than the errorMsg, I want to hide the errorMsg

Below is the code I have written;

```
$(document).bind("touchstart",function(e){
         if(e.target.id != "checkbox_err")
        $("span#checkbox_err").fadeOut("slow");
     });
}


$("input:checkbox").bind("touchstart",function(){
$("span#checkbox_err").fadeIn("fast");

});
```

Now the issue is when I click/touch on the checkbox, the errorMsg shows for a while and then it also hides it immediately (since target is not the errorMsg)

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try .blur() instead of .mouseout()

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because of bubbling?
It makes sense to me, the event will reach the underlying layer which is not the target.
So you have to stop eventPropagation:

```
$("input:checkbox").bind("touchstart",function(){
$("span#checkbox_err").fadeIn("fast");
event.stopPropagation.

});
```

Hope it helps ya.
Did you happen to find an alternative for mouseout? - which brought me here.

Answer (score 1):

> this example will surely help you ! http://jsfiddle.net/PzTcS/12/, It works well on iPad.

Answer (score -1):

You could try with **GestureEnd()** event in ipad

Comment: Isn't GestureEnd for multiple touch and not for single touch...I am looking for the equivalent of blur/mouseout..

Comment: @Diana : there are no such event like mouesout and mouseover in touch enviroment.Have a look on  http://backtothecode.blogspot.com/2009/10/javascript-touch-and-gesture-events.html

Comment: Right...But is there any workaround to implement the equivalent of mouseout ?

Comment: @diana : No..How can u use mouse event .if u dont have mouse to use ipad

Comment: See you don't understand the question.. Even there is no hover event on iPad, we use "touchstart" to kind of simulate that behavior...So along similar lines...I HOPE u get the question now...

Comment: You can use **touchend** event

Comment: @Diana let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2306/discussion-between-gourav-khanna-and-diana)