# jQuery mouseout issue on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad, safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery mouseout on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994160/jquery-mouseout-on-ipad)

I am testing a page on iPad and am facing some issues implementing an equivalent of mouseout behavior..

So the issue is very simple to understand;
 1. On my page, there is a checkbox on click (or rather touch), I want to show an errorMsg
 2. On click/touch on anything other than the errorMsg, I want to hide the errorMsg

Below is the code I have written;

```
$(document).bind("touchstart",function(e){
         if(e.target.id != "checkbox_err")
        $("span#checkbox_err").fadeOut("slow");
     });
}


$("input:checkbox").bind("touchstart",function(){
$("span#checkbox_err").fadeIn("fast");

});
```

Now the issue is when I click/touch on the checkbox, the errorMsg shows for a while and then it also hides it immediately (since target is not the errorMsg)

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Please don't re-post your questions. If you want to add more information, just edit your first question. This will also place your question back on the front page, which might help to attract more answers.

Comment: If you read the question carefully, it is quite different from what you have linked as duplicate ..